# Visualforce Error :Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

Can any one help me out with this Error .I'm getting

`Visual force Error :Attempt to de-reference a null object` .

To  identify the same product name in a table in a visual force page which is in a PDF format . I tried adding few lines in the code and it throws an Error .

Any help is very much appreciated.

**Visual Force Code**

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" 
        applyHtmlTag="false" renderAs="PDF" showheader="false" applyBodyTag="false" extensions="QuoteContentController">



    <div class="title"> <center> <h2>RFQ Information  </h2> </center> </div>
  <!-- <b>General Information  </b> -->
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" >
        <tr>

            <th bgcolor="Silver">General</th>
            <th bgcolor="Silver">Information:</th>
            <th bgcolor="Silver">Justification and Account </th>
            <th bgcolor="Silver">Information:</th>

         </tr>
       <!-- </table>
    <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">-->
       <!-- <tr width="10%">
        <td style="border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;" align="left" width="10%">
        <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">
            <td class="labelCol" >QuoteNumber:</td>
            <td class="data2Col"><apex:outputText value="{!Quote.QuoteNumber}"/></td>
             </f>
        </td>-->
            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">QuoteNumber:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quote.QuoteNumber}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">RFQ Justification:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Name}"/></td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
            <td> <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">CustomerName: </f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Name}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Main Customers of Account:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Main_Customers_of_Account__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td> <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Account Type:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Recordtype.Name}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Bridgelux Competition at Account:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Bridgelux_Competition_at_Account__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td> <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Date:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Effective_Date__c}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Geographic regions serviced:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Servicing_Region__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Expected Order Date:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Effective_Date__c}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Annual lighting revenue:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Annual_LED_Revenue__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Internal Comments:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Description}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Annual LED revenue or percent:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Annual_LED_Revenue__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">External Comments: </f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Comments__c}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Annual Purchases of LED Sources (SAM):</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Annual_Purchases_of_LED_Sources_SAM__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Probability(%):</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunity.Probability}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Percent of LED purchases that are COB:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Segment:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Other Info:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Application:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Persona:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Geography:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunity.Region__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

           <!-- <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Opportunity RecordType:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunity.RecordType.Name}"/></td>
            </tr> -->

          </table>


   <h3>QuotelineItems Details</h3>
    <table class="bordered">
        <thead> 
                <tr>
               <!-- <td bgcolor="Silver" class="header-table-heading">Part</td> -->
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">PartNumbers</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Price</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">EndCustomerPrice</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quantity</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Total</td>
            </tr>
          </thead> 
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!Quote.QuotelineItems}" var="qli">

            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-data" ><apex:outputText value="{!qli.Product2.Name}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data" ><apex:outputText value="{!qli.Unitprice}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!qli.End_Customer_Price__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!qli.Quantity}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!qli.TotalPrice}"/></td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table> 



     <h3>Competitive Data</h3>
    <table class="bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Company</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Product Series</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Part Numbers</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Price</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">volume</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Date Price is Valid</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!Quote.Competitor_s__r}" var="com">
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!com.Name}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!com.Product_Series__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!com.Part_Number__c }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!com.Price_Offered__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!com.Volume__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!com.Date_Price_is_Valid__c}"/></td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table> 

<h3>OpportunityForecast Details</h3>
 <table class="bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" colspan="3"  ></td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" colspan="5" >FORECAST DATE</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>              
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Opportunity Name</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">PartNumbers</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"></td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Q1 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Q2 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Q3 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Q4 2014 </td>
                <!--<td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quantity</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Price</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Amount</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quarter</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Month</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Actual Price</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Year</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Date</td>--> 
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">MonthText</td> 
               <!-- <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">ForecastDate</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">ForecastName</td>-->
                <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading">Grand<br/>Total </td> 
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <apex:repeat value="{!disp_list}" var="opf">
            <tr>

                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Opportunity}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Product}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data" >Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Amount }"/><br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Amount }"/><br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Amount }"/><br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Amount }"/><br/></td>
                <!--<td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Price }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Amount }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quarter }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Month }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.Actual_Price }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Year }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_date }"/></td> --> 
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Month_Text }"/></td> 
                <!--<td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.Forecast_Date }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.Name }"/></td>-->
                <td rowspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>



             </tr>
            </apex:repeat> 
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
                   <tr class="foot">
                      <!--<td align="right" colspan="2" width="10%" class="header-table-heading">
                              Subtotal: 
                         </td>

                         <td align="right" colspan="2" width="100%" class="header-table-heading">
                              Grandtotal: 
                         </td>
                         <td align="right" width="12%" class="subtotal">
                           <apex:OutputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity__c}"/>
                       </td>-->
                         <tr>

                     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data">SubTotal :</td>
                     <td colspan="0" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data"  >Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/> </td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity}<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount}<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     </tr>
                         <tr>

                       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left"  align="right" class="header-table-heading">GrandTotal</td>
                       <td colspan="0" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-heading"  >Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/> </td>
                       <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                       </tr>

                   </tr>
               </tfoot>
    </table> 

</apex:page>
```

Apex Code :

```
public with sharing class QuoteContentController {

       public Competitor__c com{get;set;}

       public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opflist{get;set;}

       public Id qId {get;set;}

       Public string all{get;set;}

//Declare a wrapper class  

       public class Wrapperclass{

 //custom wrapper datatype  

       Public string Name{get;set;}  
       Public string AccountType{get;set;}  
       Public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
       Public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
       Public string Probability{get;set;}  
       Public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
       Public string External_Comment{get;set;}  

       Public string Segment{get;set;}  
       Public string Application{get;set;}  
       Public string Persona{get;set;}  
       Public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}  

       Public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Total{get;set;}  

       Public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
       Public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
       Public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
       Public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
       Public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
       Public string Other_information{get;set;}  

       Public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
       Public string Volume{get;set;} 
       Public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;} 

       Public string gmod_Opportunity{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
       Public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
       Public Date gmod_date{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Month_Text{get;set;}
       Public Date  Forecast_Date{get;set;}




       Public wrapperClass(){} 

  }

       Public QuoteContentController(){}

       Public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

       qId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');

       disp_Map = new Map<String,wrapperClass>();


    }


        Public Integer subtotalofquantity{get;set;}

        Public Integer subtotalofamount{get;set;}

        public Map<String,wrapperClass> disp_Map{get;set;}


       Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{

       //subtotalofquantity=0;

      // subtotalofamount=0;

     // Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list(){
    //define constructor to instantiate the wrapper data type 

       disp_list=new list<wrapperclass>();

     //Query all the list 

     list<Quote> q =[select id ,Name ,QuoteNumber,Effective_Date__c ,Comments__c ,Quote.Opportunity.id, 
                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability ,Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c ,Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c,Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c,Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                    from Quote where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];

    // list<QuoteLineItem> qli =[Select QuoteId , PricebookEntry.Product2.Name ,Unitprice ,End_Customer_Price__c ,Quantity , TotalPrice from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId =:qId ];

   //  list<Account> a = [Select id ,Name ,Main_Customers_of_Account__c ,Bridgelux_Competition_at_Account__c,Servicing_Region__c ,
                     // Annual_LED_Revenue__c,Annual_Purchases_of_LED_Sources_SAM__c ,Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c from Account where account.id =:qId ];

   //  list<Competitor__c>  com = [Select id ,Part_Number__c,Product_Series__c,Price_Offered__c,Volume__c,Date_Price_is_Valid__c from Competitor__c ]  ; 

     Opportunity opp =[select id , Name, (select id, Quantity, product2id from OpportunityLineItems), probability, AccSegment__c from Opportunity where opportunity.Id =:q[0].opportunity.id];

    list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.id,gmod__Product__c,gmod__Quantity__c,gmod__Price__c , gmod__Month__c,    gmod__date__c,  gmod__Quarter__c ,gmod__Amount__c ,Actual_Price__c ,gmod__Year__c ,gmod__Month_Text__c ,Forecast_Date__c,gmod__Product__r.Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null and gmod__opportunity__r.id =:opp.id order by gmod__Month__c asc limit 9]; 

   // list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist=[ SELECT  id,gmod__product__r.name,gmod__Quantity__c,createdby.name , gmod__opportunity__r.name ,gmod__Amount__c,GROUPING(gmod__Quantity__c) grpQty, GROUPING(gmod__Amount__c) grpAmt ,COUNT(id) oppfc from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c GROUP BY CUBE(gmod__Quantity__c, gmod__Amount__c) ORDER BY GROUPING(gmod__Quantity__c), GROUPING(gmod__Amount__c) ];

  // Executes in DC 
  // [SELECT  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c,COUNT(id) cnt FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null GROUP BY  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c];
//Executes in DC
 /*list<AggregateResult> groupedResults   =[SELECT  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c,sum(gmod__Price__c) gmod__Price__c ,SUm(gmod__Amount__c) gmod__Amount__c,Sum(gmod__Quantity__c) gmod__Qunatity__c,COUNT(id) Quantity FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE  gmod__date__c=THIS_FISCAL_YEAR GROUP BY  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c];

 for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
   // System.debug('Campaign ID' + ar.get('CampaignId'));
    System.debug('sum amount' + ar.get('gmod__Amount__c'));
    System.debug('Count' + ar.get('Quantity'));
   // System.debug('Sum Quantity' + ar.get('gmod__Quantity__c'));


}*/

       //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  

        for (Quote qt :q){
             System.debug('Quote Size ++ '+q.size());
             System.debug('opp forcast ++ ' +opflist.size());


            for(integer i=0;i<opflist.size();i++){

            subtotalofquantity+= integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

            subtotalofamount+= integer.valueOf(opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c);


                                        //Instantiating the wrapper SObject 

                                        wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();




                         if(disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name)!= disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i-1].gmod__Product__r.Name)){

                         if(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name != opflist[i-1].gmod__Product__r.Name ){

                         if(disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name )){

                               w = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name);

                               w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                               w.gmod_Amount = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Amount + opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c;

                  } else {

                    w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                    w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;
                } 
               }

                    //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database. 

                 w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                 w.gmod_Price=opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;

                 w.Name =opflist[i].Name;

                 w.gmod_Quarter=opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;

                 w.gmod_Month=opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;

                 w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;

                 w.Actual_Price=opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;

                 w.gmod_Year=opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;

                 w.gmod_date=opflist[i].gmod__date__c;

                 w.gmod_Month_Text=opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;

                 w.Forecast_Date=opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c;

                 disp_Map.put(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name,w);

                              //Adding everthing to the List  


                            // w.name =qt.name;

                             // disp_list.add(w);

                              // return disp_list;  
                    }         
              }
       for(wrapperclass w : disp_Map.values()){
            disp_list.add(w);
 }
     }

   }  
 } //End of Class
```

Comment: Can you highlight the line you are getting the error?

Comment: @ Mihai Neagoe :It does not display any line number

Comment: This is an error in your VF page and the variables its trying to get from the controller to show on the page . Try commenting out blocks until it runs then you should be ale to work out which line is causing the problem.

Comment: @Richard Durrant:I have Updated the VF code.Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @nikkey: Try commenting out each of your tables in the VF page until it runs then put the last one you took out back in row by row and you should be able to see where the trouble is. Otherwise look back in the history and check the differences between current version and previous working one.

Comment: @Richard Durrant :The Vf page gives the o/p with out comparision. if it comment the lines from if(i == 0) for comparing  the same product name.But main scenario is to identify the same product names in a quarter and display only once.Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: @nikkey: I would have thought that this line disp_Map.put(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name,w); would be doing the filtering. If a matching product name was found the entry in the map would be replaced by the new one. btw: are you still trying to fix your VF error or getting your code to work correctly?

Comment: @Richard Durrant:Im still trying to fix the Error .Need to find the Same product name and display it. I'm completely meshed up.Is that im making any blunder mistake in the code. Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: @Richard Durrant,@Maruf Bagwan:It throw Error as :System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object 
Class.QuoteContentController.<init>: line 155, column 1.The line is : if(disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name )){

Comment: @nikkey this exception would suggest that either opflist[i[ is null or the gmod__Product__r is null. Put in some debug statements before the "if" and see which it is and work backards to find why it's null. Alternatively to stop the exception just prepend "opflist[i] != null && opflist[i].Product__c != null" to your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
public with sharing class QuoteContentController {

       public Competitor__c com{get;set;}

       public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opflist{get;set;}

       public Id qId {get;set;}

       Public string all{get;set;}

//Declare a wrapper class  

       public class Wrapperclass{

 //custom wrapper datatype  

       Public string Name{get;set;}  
       Public string AccountType{get;set;}  
       Public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
       Public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
       Public string Probability{get;set;}  
       Public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
       Public string External_Comment{get;set;}  

       Public string Segment{get;set;}  
       Public string Application{get;set;}  
       Public string Persona{get;set;}  
       Public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}  

       Public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Total{get;set;}  

       Public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
       Public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
       Public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
       Public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
       Public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
       Public string Other_information{get;set;}  

       Public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
       Public string Volume{get;set;} 
       Public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;} 

       Public string gmod_Opportunity{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
       Public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
       Public Date gmod_date{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Month_Text{get;set;}
       Public Date  Forecast_Date{get;set;}




       Public wrapperClass(){} 

  }

       Public QuoteContentController(){}

       Public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

       qId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');

       disp_Map = new Map<String,wrapperClass>();


    }


        Public Integer subtotalofquantity{get;set;}

        Public Integer subtotalofamount{get;set;}

        public Map<String,wrapperClass> disp_Map{get;set;}


       Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{

       //subtotalofquantity=0;

      // subtotalofamount=0;

     // Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list(){
    //define constructor to instantiate the wrapper data type 

       disp_list=new list<wrapperclass>();

     //Query all the list 

     list<Quote> q =[select id ,Name ,QuoteNumber,Effective_Date__c ,Comments__c ,Quote.Opportunity.id, 
                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability ,Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c ,Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c,Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c,Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                    from Quote where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];

    // list<QuoteLineItem> qli =[Select QuoteId , PricebookEntry.Product2.Name ,Unitprice ,End_Customer_Price__c ,Quantity , TotalPrice from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId =:qId ];

   //  list<Account> a = [Select id ,Name ,Main_Customers_of_Account__c ,Bridgelux_Competition_at_Account__c,Servicing_Region__c ,
                     // Annual_LED_Revenue__c,Annual_Purchases_of_LED_Sources_SAM__c ,Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c from Account where account.id =:qId ];

   //  list<Competitor__c>  com = [Select id ,Part_Number__c,Product_Series__c,Price_Offered__c,Volume__c,Date_Price_is_Valid__c from Competitor__c ]  ; 

     Opportunity opp =[select id , Name, (select id, Quantity, product2id from OpportunityLineItems), probability, AccSegment__c from Opportunity where opportunity.Id =:q[0].opportunity.id];

    list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.id,gmod__Product__c,gmod__Quantity__c,gmod__Price__c , gmod__Month__c,    gmod__date__c,  gmod__Quarter__c ,gmod__Amount__c ,Actual_Price__c ,gmod__Year__c ,gmod__Month_Text__c ,Forecast_Date__c,gmod__Product__r.Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null and gmod__opportunity__r.id =:opp.id order by gmod__Month__c asc limit 9]; 

   // list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist=[ SELECT  id,gmod__product__r.name,gmod__Quantity__c,createdby.name , gmod__opportunity__r.name ,gmod__Amount__c,GROUPING(gmod__Quantity__c) grpQty, GROUPING(gmod__Amount__c) grpAmt ,COUNT(id) oppfc from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c GROUP BY CUBE(gmod__Quantity__c, gmod__Amount__c) ORDER BY GROUPING(gmod__Quantity__c), GROUPING(gmod__Amount__c) ];

  // Executes in DC 
  // [SELECT  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c,COUNT(id) cnt FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null GROUP BY  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c];
//Executes in DC
 /*list<AggregateResult> groupedResults   =[SELECT  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c,sum(gmod__Price__c) gmod__Price__c ,SUm(gmod__Amount__c) gmod__Amount__c,Sum(gmod__Quantity__c) gmod__Qunatity__c,COUNT(id) Quantity FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE  gmod__date__c=THIS_FISCAL_YEAR GROUP BY  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c];

 for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
   // System.debug('Campaign ID' + ar.get('CampaignId'));
    System.debug('sum amount' + ar.get('gmod__Amount__c'));
    System.debug('Count' + ar.get('Quantity'));
   // System.debug('Sum Quantity' + ar.get('gmod__Quantity__c'));


}*/

       //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  

        for (Quote qt :q){
             System.debug('Quote Size ++ '+q.size());
             System.debug('opp forcast ++ ' +opflist.size());


            for(integer i=1;i<opflist.size();i++){

            subtotalofquantity+= integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

            subtotalofamount+= integer.valueOf(opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c);


                                        //Instantiating the wrapper SObject 

                                        wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

             if(i == 0) 
                     {



                         if(disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name )){

                               w = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name);

                               w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                               w.gmod_Amount = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Amount + opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c;

                  } else {

                    w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                    w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;
           }

                    //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database. 

                 w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                 w.gmod_Price=opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;

                 w.Name =opflist[i].Name;

                 w.gmod_Quarter=opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;

                 w.gmod_Month=opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;

                 w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;

                 w.Actual_Price=opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;

                 w.gmod_Year=opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;

                 w.gmod_date=opflist[i].gmod__date__c;

                 w.gmod_Month_Text=opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;

                 w.Forecast_Date=opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c;

                 disp_Map.put(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name,w);

                              //Adding everthing to the List  


                            // w.name =qt.name;

                             // disp_list.add(w);

                              // return disp_list;  

                 }
          else{


                         if(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name != opflist[i-1].gmod__Product__r.Name ){

                         if(disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name ) != disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i-1].gmod__Product__r.Name)){

                               w = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name);

                               w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                               w.gmod_Amount = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Amount + opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c;

                  } else {

                    w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                    w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;
                } 


                    //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database. 

                 w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                 w.gmod_Price=opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;

                 w.Name =opflist[i].Name;

                 w.gmod_Quarter=opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;

                 w.gmod_Month=opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;

                 w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;

                 w.Actual_Price=opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;

                 w.gmod_Year=opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;

                 w.gmod_date=opflist[i].gmod__date__c;

                 w.gmod_Month_Text=opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;

                 w.Forecast_Date=opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c;

                 disp_Map.put(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name,w);

                              //Adding everthing to the List  


                            // w.name =qt.name;

                             // disp_list.add(w);

                              // return disp_list;  



              }       
              }
         }    
       for(wrapperclass w : disp_Map.values()){
            disp_list.add(w);
      }

   }  
 } //End of Class
```

Comment: And also instantiate all your list and objects.

Comment: @ Maruf Bagwan:i get an Error as :Condition expression must be of type Boolean at line 157 column 26.The line is  if(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name )

Comment: I have updated the code, try this

Comment: @ Maruf Bagwan:It throws an Error as :Duplicate variable: w at line 279 column 25.The line is for(wrapperclass w : disp_Map.values()){

Comment: check this code

Comment: @ Maruf Bagwan:It throws an Error as :Visualforce Error :Attempt to de-reference a null object .The line number is not mentined

Comment: There must be some serious issue, let some more intelligent personalities answer this question.

Comment: :I have updated the VF code.Any help is very much appreciated.